# Is it unusual for a child to be diagnosed with diabetes?

Tags: diabetes-mellitus

Recently, I came to know that a boy in my town who is 6 years old is diabetic and many people were shocked from this news.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Type 1 diabetes is commonly diagnosed in children; type 2 diabetes is more common overall and is much less likely to be diagnosed in children, though possible.

**Longer Answer**

[Type 1 diabetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_mellitus_type_1) is caused by damage to the pancreas and depends on environmental and genetic causes, most often leading to autoimmune loss of the insulin-producing beta cells in the pancreas. Type 1 diabetes occurs because insulin levels themselves are low. It commonly begins in childhood, and is also sometimes referred to as "juvenile diabetes" although it lasts life-long. Type 1 diabetics often take insulin to replace the insulin they are not producing.

[Type 2 diabetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_mellitus_type_2), by contrast, is caused by *reduced insulin sensitivity* and develops over time (lack of insulin can also eventually occur). Obesity and other lifestyle factors are strong influences on the development of type 2 diabetes, though genetics can also play a role. Type 2 diabetes is most often diagnosed in adults (and is also referred to as adult-onset diabetes, though it is also possible to occur in children), increases with age, and is overall more prevalent than type 1 diabetes, so this is likely where your community's surprise comes from.

Comment: Your overall answer is correct, but I'd add that type 2 diabetes runs in families, while type 1 does not. There are MHC associations with type 1 because it is autoimmune in origin, but clinically, we don't think of type 1 diabetes as a genetic disease.

Comment: I focused on the first phrase (type 1 diabetes is caused by genetic factors), but on looking again, you should probably correct the rest of the sentence. The specific cause of type 1 diabetes is usually known. It is autoimmune destruction of islet cells. I'd have to look it up again to be sure, but I believe anti islet cell antibodies are identified in almost all cases.

Comment: If you are going to edit, I recommend directly answering the question instead of posting information for the asker to infer from.

Comment: @DeNovo My understanding is that type 1 diabetes has quite a high heritability, and concurrence in families is rare only because the disease itself is rare, i.e., the heritable factors are a risk rather than a clear cause. I can certainly try to reference better if this is unclear or controversial, I wasn't realizing that it was.

Comment: @Cell If you are referring to my edit of the question title, I did so due to the body of the question which in my experience is usually a better marker for what new question-askers are going for here at biology.SE. I've added a more clear direct answer, however.

Comment: That's just the way it was taught in medical school (though that was a while ago)-- family history is more important for type 2 than type 1, so it was jarring for me to see type 1 described as a genetic (rather than autoimmune) disease, with the heritable component of type 2 downplayed. I'd appreciate some better sourcing if you want to contrast them in this way. Though I'm not sure you need it for the answer. Genetic doesn't necessarily mean "appears in childhood", as I'm sure you understand.

Comment: A quick search brought me to [this review on type 2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3746083/) and [this one on type 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2889752/). They're both highly heritable, but when you compare apples to apples, it looks like what I was taught in medical school still holds. Type 2 is more heritable than type 1.

Comment: @DeNovo The twin concordance is higher in type 2 because prevalence is higher, but it doesn't really look like type 2 is more heritable biologically, at best they are similar. That review on type 2 also says that a lot of the type 2 heritability is explained by heritability of obesity. I don't disagree that what you learned clinically is relevant clinically, though.

Comment: If obesity mediates the heritability of T2DM, it doesn't make T2DM less heritable. Obesity isn't just associated with T2DM, it is on the causal pathway. This means obesity isn't a confounder.  You say T1DM is caused by genetic factors and T2DM is caused by environmental factors, though genetics can also play a role. I don't see any support for that contrast, and it is in conflict with standard teaching on the pathogenesis of the two diseases. If you want to make that argument (which you don't need to do in order to answer the question), I think you should include some non wikipedia sources.

Comment: @DeNovo As you point out, since it isn't necessary to answer the question, I can make the contrast less obvious.